# No se localiza parámetro entre apostrofes en cadena de consulta

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Tengo una consulta en cadena en la cual quiero que el parámetro este entre apostrofes:

```
select * from miTabla t
where t.nombre = ':nombre'
```

Sin embargo al depurar el codigo me dice que no encuentra el parametro:

```
protected bool validaNombre(string n, NHibernate.ISession sesion){


var resultado = sesion.CreateSQLQuery(Queries.getQuery("consultaNombre"))
                .SetParameter("nombre", n)
                .UniqueResult();
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6764230/4092887) y ajusta tu consulta.

Comment: No resultó. Ahi utilizan apostrofes en una cadena especifica pero en mi caso las apostrofes hacen que no encuentre el parámetro.

Comment: Me temo que no te comprendo bien, Considera usar procedimientos almacenados. Si es posible, actualiza tu pregunta con mas información para que otros usuarios te ayuden. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

para definir un parámetro en tu consulta no se establecen con los apostrofes, una cadena entre apostrofes es una cadena fija. Por lo que quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
select * from miTabla t where t.nombre = :nombre -- eliminar los apostrofes de tu query
```

Te pongo como ejemplo también el siguiente código

```
protected bool validaNombre(string n, NHibernate.ISession sesion){

var resultado = sesion.CreateSQLQuery("select * from miTabla t where t.nombre = :nombre")
                .SetParameter("nombre", n)
                .UniqueResult();
```